# Binding native Android (and iOS) libraries in MAUI

Tags: android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android, maui

We are working on an Android and iOS (but we want to just get Android working for now) application that needs to rely on some native drivers (.so, .a and some .ini files). The company providing those drivers also provides a Xamarin project to showcase how the drivers are used. They seem to be storing those driver and other files as assets (.ini files under `Assets/Files` and .so files under `Assets/lib/arm64-v8a` and `Assets/lib/armeabi-v7a` respectively) and extracting the former using the following code:

```cs
void ExtractAssets()
{
    var assets = ApplicationContext.Assets;
    var paths = assets.List("Files");

    foreach (var path in paths)
    {
        // Read the compressed file and extract
        string readPath = Path.Combine("Files", path);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[32000];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        using (var inStream = assets.Open(readPath))
        using (var outStream = ApplicationContext.OpenFileOutput(path, Android.Content.FileCreationMode.Private))
        {
            do
            {
                bytesRead = inStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                if (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    outStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }
            while (bytesRead > 0);
        }

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Extracted '{0}' to '{1}'", readPath, path));
    }
}
```

Since Xamarin is becoming obsolete and MAUI is the next big thing, we decided to build our project on that. My colleague and I have spent the entire afternoon on a sample project and we still do not manage to simply load a `libhello-jni.so` file (we use [this one](https://github.com/uber/okbuck/blob/master/another-app/jniLibs/armeabi/libhello-jni.so)) at runtime to call a `stringFromJNI()`. We tried:

- Using an Android Native Binding project — we never really got what that's about and how mappings are supposed to work
- Trying to include the `libhello-jni.so` file as an asset and load it using `JavaNative.LoadLibrary("hello-jni");` and this had various unsuccessful results, it either did not find the library at all or it was complaining about the lib being built for x86 time processor instead of x64.

Can anyone please help us with some sample code allowing us to just simply bind a native `.so` file in a MAUI project, or at least provide us with a good guide?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that won't work on Android.  You can have a .so file, but you can't unpack it at runtime-  it has to be bundled as part of your app as a library or it won't be executable. Notice how in your example's build.gradle it declares that folder as a jni source folder?  You'd need to do that for it to work, not include it as an asset file.

Comment: The files that are unpacked at runtime in the demo Xamarin project are `.ini` files, not the libraries themselves. I don't want to unpack the `.so` file itself at runtime, I just want to bind it in the MAUI project. The project I linked is written directly using the Android SDK and NDK, not .NET and MAUI.

**Edit:** I updated the question for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are going for or not, but we use bindings to a C library that we develop for various platforms, including Android.  The way to correctly place native libraries into the final APK is via the `EmbeddedNativeLibrary` type in .csproj as demonstrated [here](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-net/blob/dbc99fea4a11d7fca0e498794accba1891ea1989/src/Couchbase.Lite.Support.Android/Couchbase.Lite.Support.Android.csproj#L73-L84).  This will include your native library alongside the other native libraries that the toolchain is going to create (like the .NET runtime, garbage collection native lib, etc).

One thing changed in .NET 6, however.  This affects us as an SDK distributor, because we need to include all necessary files inside of Nuget packages, so it may not affect you.  In Xamarin, when you embed native libraries, the native libraries are literally stitched into your assembly and no further files are needed.  In .NET 6, now they are all placed into a separate .aar file which also needs to be available when building the final application.

If you do everything correctly, you will see your native library inside of the APK in the lib/<arch> directory.  Our native library is not JNI, and thus we use P/Invoke so we don't need a `LoadLibrary` call but I am reasonably certain that the call should succeed with the libraries in this directory.

Comment: I figured it out in the end, but forgot about this question. Hopefully tomorrow I can put up some minimum working example.

Comment: @vladek What was your solution finally?

Comment: @maex Sorry for the late reply, I posted an answer, please let me know if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer:

1. Place native binary files under `${PROJECT_ROOT}\Resources\libs\android\${abi}`, where `${abi}` could be something like `arm64-v8a` or older `armeabi-v7a`, depending on the target of your native lib.
2. If not already set, set the build action for these native binary files as `AndroidNativeLibrary`.
3. You *should* now be able to call native library methods:

```cs
public static class NativeMaths
{
  // DllImport - first param is the library name, second is the method entry point
  [DllImport("nativemathslib", EntryPoint = "fentrypoint")]
  static extern int nativeAdd(int a, int b);
}
```

**Note:** The library name may be different based on the platform (*e.g.,* Android, iOS etc.), so what we are doing is something like:

```cs
// ${PROJECT_ROOT}\Platforms\Android\LibraryNames.cs

public static class LibraryNames
{
  public const string NativeMaths = "nativemaths";
}

public static class LibraryMethodEntryPoints
{
  public const string NativeAdd = "nativeadd";
}

// ${PROJECT_ROOT}\Platforms\iOS\LibraryNames.cs

public static class LibraryNames
{
  public const string NativeMaths = "__Internal";
}

public static class LibraryMethodEntryPoints
{
  public const string NativeAdd = "nativeadd";
}

// ${PROJECT_ROOT}\NativeMaths.cs

public static class NativeMaths
{
  [DllImport(LibraryNames.NativeMaths, EntryPoint = LibraryMethodEntryPoints.NativeAdd)]
  static extern int nativeAdd(int a, int b);
}
```

We have not tested the iOS part yet, though, since we are only working on Android for now.